# html form <select> element doesn't fire onChange()

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i'm trying to firing a javascript function from a  element to update a textbox form with a value, but i'm having a little problem, the function is not firing.

i checked on google for the issue, tried all that o found but i'm in the same place, my  element is not firing my javascript function

```js
function CheckPolenta() {
    console.log("here i'm");
    alert("here i'm alert");
}
```

```html
<form name="xs_formulario" action="compra-send.php" method="POST" id="xs_formulario" class="xs-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" id="xs_contact_name">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Correo" id="xs_contact_email">
        <p align="center"><strong>Seleccioná las Opciones que Queres en tu Plan de Hospedaje</strong></p>
        <input type="url" class="form-control" name="dominio" placeholder="Dominio, ejemplo www.tunombre.com" id="dominio">
        <p>Registro de Dominio<br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="xs_dominio_pago" value="dpago" id="xs_dominio_pago" onClick="ChooseDPago()">Dominio Pago</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="xs_dominio_propio" value="dpropio" id="xs_dominio_propio" onClick="ChooseDPropio()">Dominio Propio</label><br>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="xs_dominio_gratis" value="dgratis" id="xs_dominio_gratis" onClick="ChooseDGratis()">Dominio Gratis (.tk / .ml / .ga / .cf / .gq)</label>
        </p>
        <p> Tipo de Pago<br>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="xs_mensual" value="mensual" id="xs_mensual_0" onClick="ChooseMensual()">
                Mensual</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="xs_mensual" value="anual" id="xs_mensual_1" onClick="ChooseAnual()">
                Anual</label>
            <br>
        </p>
        <input type="radio" value="Basico" name="hosting" onClick="CheckPlanPrice()" id="xs_PlanBasico">
        Hospedaje Básico<br>
        <input type="radio" value="Intermedio" name="hosting" onClick="CheckPlanPrice()" id="xs_PlanIntermedio">Hospedaje Intermedio<br>
        <input type="radio" value="Avanzado" name="hosting" onClick="CheckPlanPrice()" id="xs_PlanAvanzado">Hospedaje Avanzado<br><br>
        <select id="xs_desarrollo" name="xs_desarrollo" onChange="CheckPolenta()">
            <option value="nada">Sin Diseño</option>
            <option value="html">Web HTML5</option>
            <option value="wordpress">Wordpress</option>
            <option value="eshop">Tienda en Línea</option>
            <option value="galeria">Galería</option>
            <option value="foro">Foros</option>
            <option value="social">Red Social</option>
        </select><br>
        <div id="total_pagar" name="total_pagar" align="justify">Total a Pagar <input type="text" id="total_pesos" name="total_pesos"> Pesos.</div><br>

        <textarea name="massage" placeholder="Algun otro comentario, que quiera agregar a su orden" id="x_contact_massage" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="xs-btn-wraper">
        <input name="xs_contact_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="xs_contact_submit" value="Enviar Ahora">
    </div>
</form>
```

my javascript function is in the head section, all the others functions are working fine, but those functions are triggered using onClick events.

please anyone can help me to fix this issue ?

thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: <script type="JavaScript"> might fix it

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You function is firing for me. Maybe you could make this a runnable snippet using the `<>` button in the editor.

Comment: Is there an error in your developer console?

Comment: Tried the code in Chrome, Firefox, IE 11, and Edge.. the select drop-down appears to fire the alert box as expected in all of them. Did you specify which browser you are trying this in? Side-comment I believe that technically the html attribute names like "onclick" are all lowercase.

Comment: Now we got me wondering. Here is a JSFiddle of this.. if I paste the function into the JS area, it does not fire when the select is changed. If I declare the function inside a <script></script> tag in the head (not sure if they are doing this in their actual code), the function fires. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=eorIkUK9vP

Comment: @JohnFantastico The JS area of JSFiddle runs inside an `onload` listener by default. You can change it in the "JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS)" dropdown, under Load Type.

Comment: Yep that works, thanks. So again, unless they aren't actually loading the javascript onchange function correctly, it works, in all browsers.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the event listener like this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("xs_desarrollo").addEventListener("change", function() {
         console.log("here i'm");
         alert("here i'm alert");
    })
 </script>
```

It is working perfectly for me, if it does not work for you then you have some problem in other part of your code may be script issue, please have a look on browser console by pressing F12.

Ans also make some modification here:

```
>  <select id="xs_desarrollo" name="xs_desarrollo" >
>             <option value="nada">Sin Diseño</option>
>             <option value="html">Web HTML5</option>
>             <option value="wordpress">Wordpress</option>
>             <option value="eshop">Tienda en Línea</option>
>             <option value="galeria">Galería</option>
>             <option value="foro">Foros</option>
>             <option value="social">Red Social</option>
>         </select>
```

Comment: tried your method, but still not geting the alert box when i select any value on the dropdown list. if i use the code for the form and the javascript in a clean html it's working fine.